# using .map function gives PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "materials.id" in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql, grouping

This is probably an easy one for an experienced programer, but since I´m building up on experience it seems that I'm stuck on this on... Please Help!!

I'm learning ruby on rails by building an app.
I'm using `f.select`for my users to select a certain type of material they use.
And then the user is able to insert a certain amount of weight for each material. That part is working fine.

Then I want the user to be able to see how many Kilograms he is using of each material in a view called 'views/pages/home.html.erb'

I'm able to display the total amount of `:material_weight` in the view, but when I want to show the `:material_weight` categorised by `MATERIAL_TYPES` by using `.map` and `.group`. Rails throws back this Error:

`PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "materials.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT "materials".* FROM "materials" WHERE "materials"."user_id" = $... ^ : SELECT "materials".* FROM "materials" WHERE "materials"."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY "materials"."material_type"`

for the `@material_heavy`line in the `pages_controller.rb`

I some how need to categorize the weight for each material_type the user selects, but I'm not sure how to do that.
Can anyone please advise me

**EDITED** **@material_heavy** **line**
class PagesController < ApplicationController

```
  def home
    @materials = current_user.materials
    @material_heavy = current_user.materials.group(:material_type).map { |mt| mt.(['Heavy'].group.sum(:material_weight)) } 
  end
end
```

in my `material.rb` model I have tis snippet

```
class Material < ActiveRecord::Base
  MATERIAL_TYPES = [['Heavy'], ['Medium'], ['Mild'], ['Soft']]
end
```

**ADDED MATERIALS TABLE**
materials part of schema.rb

```
create_table "materials", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "material_type"
 t.decimal  "material_weight"
 t.decimal  "material_cost"
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
 t.datetime "date"
end
```

Here is the input form were the `f.select`is located

```
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :date, class: 'form-text'%>
   <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
 <br />
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :material_type %>
    <%= f.select(:material_type, options_for_select(Material::MATERIAL_TYPES)) %>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :material_weight %> :<%= f.number_field :material_weight, class: 'form-fields'  %> -kg.
  </div>
  <br />

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :material_cost %> :
    <%= f.number_field :material_cost, class: 'form-fields' %> -Kr.
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit "Add Material" %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: The issue is that `current_user.materials.group(:material_type)` will return a Hash, but `:material_weight` is, seemingly, not a key in the hash so `sum(:material_weight)` won't work.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I'm not sure how I can see the total weight for each material type ?

Comment: What does the `materials` table look like?

Comment: @Abraham Sangha I've added the materials part from the schema.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a collection of `material` objects of `material_type` = 'Heavy':

```
@current_user.materials.where(material_type: 'Heavy')
```

If you don't mind the addition occurring at the model level:

```
 @current_user.materials.where(material_type: 'Heavy').pluck(:material_weight).reduce(:+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres is not like MySQL. It is very strict about `GROUP BY` on how it wants your query to be like. It seems to me you are breaking the Rails convention somewhere. I see a few problems and I will comment on them, maybe they are related to your problem , maybe not.

`MATERIAL_TYPES = [['Heavy'], ['Medium'], ['Mild'], ['Soft']]`
Why is this a 2-dimensional list? When you use `[]` you create a list. You created a nested list that I can find no reason to exist. But it is your application so please ignore me

Please check `scopes` for what you are trying to do. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html